# Magento ajax contact form with validation

Tags: ajax, magento

I use the ajax to send my form of contact without reloading contact page. Without ajax, the validation of fields does well but with ajax, the reloading is always successfully without validation. 
How validated my fields before the reloading?

```
<form name="contactForm" id="contactForm">                            
    <button type="button" onclick="fsubm()"  title="<?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Submit') ?>" class="button"></button></form>

function fsubm(){             


var contactForm = new VarienForm('contactForm', true);    
if (contactForm.validator && contactForm.validator.validate()) {             
    new Ajax.Updater({
        success:'contactForm'
    }, 
        '<?php echo $this->getUrl('contacts/index/post') ?>', 
        {
            method:'post', 
            action:"/contacts/index/post", 
            asynchronous:true, 
            evalScripts:false, 
            onSuccess:function(request, json){
                Element.hide('ajaxnotice');
                Element.hide('overlay');
                Element.hide('contactForm');
                Element.show('successmessage');


            },
            onFailure:function(request,json){
                alert('error');
            }, 
            onLoading:function(request, json){
                Element.show('ajaxnotice');
                Element.show('overlay');

            },  
            // parameters: $(contactForm).serialize(true),           
            parameters:Form.serialize($('contactForm')),
        });             
}
```

}

Comment: can you try : onclick="event.preventDefault(); fsubm();"

Comment: the result is the same, no validation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed  `onclick="fsubm()"` and added

```
$x('#contactForm').submit( 
    function fsubm(){    
     var contactForm = new VarienForm('contactForm', true);    
     event.preventDefault(); 
...
})
```